# Нужна аналогия кода на другом языке (из с++ в java)

Tags: java, c++

```
ctd::cout << "какой-то текст";
ctd::cin >> peremennaya;

    //Поясняю: нужно чтобы перед введением переменной я понимал что ввожу
    //Пример: Введите первое число (я понимаю что нужно ввести)
```

Comment: Лень 80-го уровня, в самом деле...

Comment: А я все равно плюсану - новичок же :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;  

class HelloWorld{  
    public static void main (String[] args) {  

        System.out.print("Введите первое число " );  
        int peremennaya = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();  
        System.out.print(peremennaya);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот код не скомпилируется.